# Android load fragment content after ViewPager has finished scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a ViewPager to control the transition between my fragments, but how can I load a fragment content only after the viewpager scroll is finished?

Edit:

I'm using an AsyncTask to load content, but if the page is still scrolling when the data is loaded into the fragment it experiences a little freeze before the scroll is finished

Comment: Your next fragment is already "loaded" as it is already visible.
If you really want to show a specific content exactly when the scroll finished, you can use an onPageListener on the viewpager and get the viewpager state :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)

Comment: I've edited my question